# PHP script that accessing https site in browser

Tags: php, curl, https

I just started learning about using php scripts today and I'm trying to access a site that is https, but the example code on the php site doesn't seem to be working. Both curl and ssl are enabled on my php. Any insights would be welcomed! Thanks!

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.facebook.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//grab url and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this **`cURL`** param to your existing set since you are accessing a HTTPs URL.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

---

### From the docs...

> Set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the peer's
>   certificate.

**`EDIT :`**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.facebook.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$resp=curl_exec($ch);
echo($resp);// <----------------- You will be taken to facebook page.
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Shankar. I added your cURL param to my existing set and it still doesn't seem to be working. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I need to install a debugger as I'm just running these scripts via the browser on my localhost. I'll need to get back to you on that one!